# javascript clock not rotating which i think is due to javascript

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial to learn how to code the js clock. my HTML and CSS worked well just like the video however when I finished the js, the clock's hands were not rotating

Here is my code

```js
setInterval(setClock, 1000)

const hourHand = document.querySelector('[data-hour-hand]')
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('[data-minute-hand]')
const secondHand = document.querySelector('[data-second-hand]')


function setClock() {
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const secondsRatio = currentDate.getSeconds() / 60
    const minutesRatio = (secondsRatio + currentDate.getMinutes()) / 60
    const hoursRatio = (minutesRatio + currentDate.getHours()) / 12
    
}

setRotation(secondHand, secondsRatio)
setRotation(minuteHand, minutesRatio)
setRotation(hourHand, hoursRatio)


function setRotation(element, rotationRatio) {
    element.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotationRatio * 360)
}

setClock()
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
    --rotation: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 {--rotation: 30deg;}
.clock .number2 {--rotation: 60deg;}
.clock .number3 {--rotation: 90deg;}
.clock .number4 {--rotation: 120deg;}
.clock .number5 {--rotation: 150deg;}
.clock .number6 {--rotation: 180deg;}
.clock .number7 {--rotation: 210deg;}
.clock .number8 {--rotation: 240deg;}
.clock .number9 {--rotation: 270deg;}
.clock .number10 {--rotation: 300deg;}
.clock .number11 {--rotation: 330deg;}


.clock .hand {
    --rotation: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
    

}

.clock::after {

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.clock .hand.second {
    width: 3px;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute {
    width: 7px;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: black;
}

.clock .hand.hour {
    width: 10px;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
  <div class="hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
  <div class="hand second" data-second-hand></div>
  <div class="number number1">1</div>
  <div class="number number2">2</div>
  <div class="number number3">3</div>
  <div class="number number4">4</div>
  <div class="number number5">5</div>
  <div class="number number6">6</div>
  <div class="number number7">7</div>
  <div class="number number8">8</div>
  <div class="number number9">9</div>
  <div class="number number10">10</div>
  <div class="number number11">11</div>
  <div class="number number12">12</div>
</div>
```

I took a reference from a video tutorial where he used const to set `hourRatio` `secondRatio` and `minuteRatio` and linked everything at the end but this didn't work for me.

Any help?

Comment: move the calls to the `setRotation` function inside of the `setClock` function under the ratio calculations

Answer (score 3):

```js
setInterval(setClock, 1000)

const hourHand = document.querySelector('[data-hour-hand]')
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('[data-minute-hand]')
const secondHand = document.querySelector('[data-second-hand]')


function setClock() {
  const currentDate = new Date()
  const secondsRatio = currentDate.getSeconds() / 60
  const minutesRatio = (secondsRatio + currentDate.getMinutes()) / 60
  const hoursRatio = (minutesRatio + currentDate.getHours()) / 12
  setRotation(secondHand, secondsRatio)
  setRotation(minuteHand, minutesRatio)
  setRotation(hourHand, hoursRatio)

}



function setRotation(element, rotationRatio) {
  element.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotationRatio * 360)
}

setClock()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 {
  --rotation: 30deg;
}

.clock .number2 {
  --rotation: 60deg;
}

.clock .number3 {
  --rotation: 90deg;
}

.clock .number4 {
  --rotation: 120deg;
}

.clock .number5 {
  --rotation: 150deg;
}

.clock .number6 {
  --rotation: 180deg;
}

.clock .number7 {
  --rotation: 210deg;
}

.clock .number8 {
  --rotation: 240deg;
}

.clock .number9 {
  --rotation: 270deg;
}

.clock .number10 {
  --rotation: 300deg;
}

.clock .number11 {
  --rotation: 330deg;
}

.clock .hand {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: translate(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 11;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second {
  width: 3px;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute {
  width: 7px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: black;
}

.clock .hand.hour {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
  <div class="hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
  <div class="hand second" data-second-hand></div>
  <div class="number number1">1</div>
  <div class="number number2">2</div>
  <div class="number number3">3</div>
  <div class="number number4">4</div>
  <div class="number number5">5</div>
  <div class="number number6">6</div>
  <div class="number number7">7</div>
  <div class="number number8">8</div>
  <div class="number number9">9</div>
  <div class="number number10">10</div>
  <div class="number number11">11</div>
  <div class="number number12">12</div>
</div>
```

You had setRotation calls outside of the setClock function, where your ratios are set...